# Private CA management with browser-based self-service front end

Tags: security, authentication

I'm considering moving to certificate-based authentication for some internal browser-based resources, and I'd like to have some way of my users being able to issue and revoke their own certificates using a private CA.  Not all of my users are technical so I'd like the user interface to be browser-based with the back-end running on a secure server that I'll provide.

Is there an open-source solution that can—

- issue and revoke certificates for users based on their existing credentials (i.e. the page will be protected by some other form of authentication)
- maintain a CRL for revoked certificates
- have some kind of super-user management interface?

I've looked at [XCA](http://xca.sourceforge.net/) but this is a Windows application that runs locally.  I need the equivalent but in the form of a site my users can visit.